# Can I hide partitions so that they are not affected by Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I would like to install Ubuntu into unused space on my HD without removing or damaging existing partitions.  The most important partition is a recovery partition (HP).

Answer (score 0):

- No, you can not. Partitions shown during the installer are not shown from the operating system but from a tool called "gParted". Since it does not know what you want to do with the partitions it should always be possible to always remove any partition (including recovery partitions).
- The Ubuntu installer does not mess up partitions *you* do not touch. So as long as you pick the unallocated space it is going to install into that space and nowhere else. As an extra feature the partition part of the installer will put comments next to the partition with a text explaining what it is. It will show what the recovery partition is.
- Oh and recovery partitions you can re-create in case you do remove it. So even it *you* do mess up it nothing is lost. Just a matter of making a same size partition and a download of the HP recovery software.